# When I click back button I can see my last protected page

Tags: php, web

In my web site I destroy session but after logout if users press back on browser they can see last page.

How can I solve this ? I tried javascript but didn't work. I tried unset or destroy session but that doesn't work too. What I can do ?

I use these codes at header.

```
Header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
Header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

How can I solve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why does it matter?  If your app does authentication and such properly, they won't be able to do anything anyway....

Comment: I know but my employer don't want to see that page :), @cHao

Comment: Well, then, your employer doesn't know how a web browser works.

Comment: @cHao my employer doesn't know how to use computers.

Comment: You may want to let them know that this is not unusual, and that they don't have complete control over the browser, before they have you trying to disable right-click or prevent leaving the site or something.  "But you could do it before..." == precedent, and their requests will get more and more idiotic til you're tearing your hair out in frustration.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The page was sent to the client, it's up to the client to decide what to do with it.

What's the difference between this behaviour and a user with a photographic memory?

The real question is: why would you want to do this?

Comment: This is only true if the client loads the page from memory or disk cache. Perhaps @SahinYanlık should verify whether this is the case or not (for example by checking the webserver logs).

Comment: @AnotherCode If the client saw the page before, that means it has accessed it (from server or cache is irrelevant).  So you can never prevent them from revisiting it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a cache in the browser, you cannot control it exactly. The best you could do is time-stamp the page on creation (use a hidden field, perhaps), and have some javascript onLoad that redirects or formats the page if it finds that the time since the time-stamp is beyond some limit.

But this is not going to prevent someone looking at someone else's history; only clearing one's history will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the session with javascript (probably AJAX) on the dom:loaded event. If the session is destroyed, you can redirect the user. Also, if you choose this way, you have to grab your content with AJAX too - ofcourse after the session validation.